# How to convert string to Cassandra.TimeUuid in c#

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I am using Cassandra database in c#. I have a User table and it's have UserId column of `TimeUuid` type. Now the scenario is i have to pass UserId as string parameter in third party library's method. and in this method i have to convert this string to `Cassandra.TimeUuid`.

How can i convert this string to `Cassandra.TimeUuid` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to create a `TimeUuid` instance from string is to do:

```
TimeUuid time = (TimeUuid) Guid.Parse(value);
```

Thanks to the [implicit conversion operator defined in `TimeUuid` class](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/3.3.2/src/Cassandra/TimeUuid.cs#L203-L206).

It's not very intuitive so I've created a [ticket to expose `TimeUuid.Parse()` method](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-592).